How to hide these directories in react
How to hide source code in these directories in react
I haven't used the create-react-app version. I tried using GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false, but it didn't work.
I've tried using the below script, but it can't remove source maps.
build":  "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false && npm run build",
Img

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
